# Azure VM extremely slow connection

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I created a Standard B1s Windows VM instance where I'm running OpenSSH service and using it as a SFTP server.
All works perfectly fine for about 2 hours, I can RDP to the VM nicely and SSH connection works fine.

After about 2 hours the connection to VM becomes very slow in a way that RDP takes around a minute and SSH connection times out every time.
What fixes a problem for a short time is restarting the VM or resizing it to any other tier. Then again everything works fine for about 2 hours, then problem appears again.

I'm aware that B1s is a Burst type VM but we are using it as simple SFTP server where 2-3 times a day one document will be uploaded. So no high CPU or Memory occupancy is needed. I also tried resizing it to non B-class VM, but the problem is the same. We are located in East USA and server is also located in that Azure region.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: I had similar issue when using Linux VM with this small size, check CPU utilization and mainly the Log Analytics agents, sometimes it gets stuck a overloads the VM.

Comment: There's really no way to know, based on what you provided, as you haven't shared any code or any other details. Note: this also doesn't seem to be about programming, and likely fits better on SuperUser (although it would be off-topic there too, as written - you really need to include details - processes running, cpu/network utilization, etc.)

Answer (score -1):

Try accessing the VM from somewhere else. Maybe its a network related problem? Create a VM in Europe West and execute the same operations. If this is causing no issues then I would try to dig deeper in network related topics.

Comment: FYI this isn't an answer, but a few troubleshooting ideas. Best as a comment, not as an answer.